Postgres peer authentication not working despite proper mapping
Long-time Stack Overflow lurker, first time caller. I'm trying to open a PostgreSQL database in the command line, but I keep getting the following error:
~$ psql -d blog_db -U blogger
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "blogger"

This is in Ubuntu.
My OS username is peter so I am mapping it to the Postgres usernames in my pg_ident.conf file:
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
peter       peter           all

and it appears to have registered:
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_ident_file_mappings;
 map_number |               file_name               | line_number | map_name | sys_name | pg_username | error 
------------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------
          1 | /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_ident.conf |          73 | peter    | peter    | all         | 
(1 row)


I have also updated my pg_hba.conf file:
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             postgres                                peer map=peter
local   all             blogger                                 peer map=peter

and it appears to have been read correctly:
3 | /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf |         124 | local | {all}         | {postgres} | peer          | {map=peter} | 
4 | /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf |         125 | local | {all}         | {blogger} | peer          | {map=peter}

I have also reset the database using both systemctl restart and systemctl reload, but no dice. Rebooted my machine as well, just in case. I guess I could just change authentication to password instead of peer, but I'm really curious why these settings don't work. Any ideas?? Or at least next steps I could take to troubleshoot? Thanks!!

The problem is the first line in your pg_hba.conf:
local   all             all                                     peer

PostgreSQL uses the first line in pg_hba.conf that matches the incoming connection request. Now this line has no map, so no map is used, and your connection fails.

That was it, thank you so much!! So that particular setting supersedes all the other settings? I would have thought that the more specific postgres/blogger settings took precedence.

Define "more specific". No, the rule is simple: the first line that matches the connection request is used, all further lines are ignored.

Got it, thanks again!
